# FCM Token is invalidating for chrome frequently

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

FCM Token is invalidating for chrome frequently, But it's working for firefox. 
I have implemented `onTokenRefresh()` callback.
Here is my implementation

`messaging.onTokenRefresh(function () {
    console.log("refresh token called(webpush)");
    messaging.getToken().then(function (refreshedToken) {
        console.log('Token refreshed.', refreshedToken);
        // post data to db
    });
});`

How to check that above implementation is working properly. Not able to save the refreshed token to our DB.

Comment: I think you can call this method directly in another function, say function `f(){ ...}` which you can call `f()` on a custom event. This way you can check if your code works properly or not. The real invocation of `messaging.onTokenRefresh` should not be your concern, it is up to google to invoke it whenever needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the on token refresh callback is not used. But it will be in a future update.

If you wanted to check your logic you could just pull out the callback and call i directly

```
const onRefreshCb = function() {
  messaging.getToken()......
};

messaging.onTokenRefresh(onRefreshCb);
```

To test you'd just call `onRefreshCb()` to test out your logic, using [deleteToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging#deleteToken) if you wanted to ensure you would get a new token.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful reply. 
FCM Token is invalidating for chrome frequently, But it's working for firefox. Please suggest

Comment: @Gaunt Face The problem is when FCM invalidates the token in background. The browser then becomes unaddressable to the server which can't remotely call onRefreshCb.

Comment: FCM does not currently invalidate the token. When it does eventually invalidate the token it will not invalidate it until the browser has had a chance to trigger onTokenRefresh callbak.

Note: I work on the FCM library at Google.